# Protecting Form Action Attribute from XSS with PHP Validation

Tags: php, forms, action, xss

It's impossible to stop form manipulation on a webpage. Whether your form has no `action=""` at all, or it's empty, or specifies something, a user can change this how ever they like.

However, that doesn't mean that we have to allow the form to execute if they do.

Let's say the form's action attribute is set to `#submit`:

```
<form method="post" action="#submit">
<p>Name:<br /><input type="text" name="sign" size="35" /></p>
<p>Email:<br /><input type="email" name="email" size="35" required /></p>
<p>Message:<br /><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Is there no way to simply kill the form if the action is changed from the default?

```
<?php

if ( $_POST['action'] == '#submit' ) {

$to      = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'Inquiry | Company Name';
$name    = trim( stripslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['sign'] ) ) );
$email   = trim( stripslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['email'] ) ) );
$message = trim( stripslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['message'] ) ) );

$validated = true;

if ( !$validated ) {
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=fail" />';
exit;
}

$body  = "";
$body .= "Name: ";
$body .= $name;
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "Email: ";
$body .= $email;
$body .= "\n\n";
$body .= $message;
$body .= "\n";

$success = mail( $to, $subject, $body, "From: <$email>" );

if ( $success ) {
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=success" />';
} else {
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=fail" />';
}

}

?>
```

Comment: What is the threat that this would mitigate? How is this related to xss?

Comment: For example, JS can be injected like so `action="javascript:alert('Hello')"`. But, that script can't be activated through the post method unless the form validates. Of course, you might be thinking well they can just create an entirely new form in the DOM and execute it no matter what you do, but the concern is that it's an actual form that also has code/data going on server-side that then goes into a database or to someone's email from my IP. I'm sure I am failing to understand logic in some context, but just to err on the side of caution, wouldn't it be good to lock this down?

Comment: You'd have to give the user the opportunity to inject code, they can't just manipulate your files at will, but they can hit your endpoints remotely. Depending on what the endpoints do, that may or may not be a problem. In the case of a `mail()` function, that could be a problem. You could use session tokens to match against, that would help reduce anonymous hits.

Comment: Exactly. There are so many things that may or may not happen, that my security mind has been conditioned to just lock it down. There don't have to be good reasons to use strong security; the unknown is all that is required. The reason I'm so concerned is that I build tools like WordPress plugins, which other people will use, so I don't have control of their entire site security nor control of context. They might hack up the code, pair it with different scripts, etc. etc. etc. My mindset is to make something as safe as possible for many possible variables.

Comment: I suppose I should have framed the question in a different way: "Is there a way to detect the contents of the action attribute in an HTML form with PHP?" This can be done with JS/jQuery, but that's not secure obviously because the user can just disable it.

Comment: If you do the basic web-based security basics, you should be fine. 1) use form tokens 2) bind parameters on sql 3) use `htmlspecialchars()` effectively 4) validate fields with some logic and/or native functions 5) use ssl  - These are the basic ones. I would say don't be paralyzed by all the different ways someone could penetrate your script. There are server-based attacks as well, so you just keep things up to date and try to make your software as secure as you can by being mindful as you write it.